Is there a way for passing multipart config to auto configured JSP Servlet on jboss eap8 with undertow, spring-web-6.1.9?
The problem
I am migrating from eap7 to 8 (also from javax to jakarta), and have a request with MultipartFile. My app is using jsp. File gets to the server, in controller it is processed (not written) then multipart resolver tries to clean up multipart, during which it expects (with jsp servlet) the multipart configuration to be present. This config is present on my declared servlet but not on the auto generated jsp servlet.
This is jsp framgent that triggers my controller:
<form:form id="myFancyForm${myEntity.id}" method="POST"
           action="addStuff?${_csrf.parameterName}=${_csrf.token}"
           enctype="multipart/form-data" class="skip">
    <input id="someId" type="hidden" name="someId" class="myIdClass"
           value="${myEntity.id}"/>

    <div class="my_fancy_button" id="SomeButtonId${myEntity.id}">
        <input id="file" name="file" type="file" class="some_class_css"
               onchange="checkFileSizeAndSubmit(this, '#myFancyForm${myEntity.id}');"/>
    </div>
</form:form>

Controller:
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addStuff", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addStuff(Model model, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file, HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
           doSomeReadLogicWithFile(file);
           return "myJspPage";
        }
    }

When return "myJspPage" is reached, the org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver kicks in with method cleanupMultipart and it does so for each servlet. My main servlet (declared in web.xml) goes through like a charm (I added xml config for multipart), but then, auto-generated jsp servlet reaches the code io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl verifyMultipartServlet, tries to get multipart config from servlet, gets null, and raises throw UndertowServletMessages.MESSAGES.multipartConfigNotPresent() exception
The stack then looks like this:

2024-07-17 12:15:05,436 WARN  [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver] (default task-53) Failed to perform cleanup of multipart items: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UT010057: multipart config was not present on Servlet
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.verifyMultipartServlet(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:567)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletRequestImpl.getParts(HttpServletRequestImpl.java:556)
    at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0.redhat-00005//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:306)
    at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0.redhat-00005//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:306)
    at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0.redhat-00005//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:306)
    at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0.redhat-00005//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequestWrapper.getParts(HttpServletRequestWrapper.java:306)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver.cleanupMultipart(StandardServletMultipartResolver.java:122)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.cleanupMultipart(DispatcherServlet.java:1268)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1125)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:979)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0.redhat-00005//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:547)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.api@6.0.0.redhat-00005//jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:614)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:129)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//my.app.packaging.filters.HttpHeadFilter.doFilter(HttpHeadFilter.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//my.app.packaging.filters.MyAppSecurityFilter.doFilter(MyAppSecurityFilter.java:28)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:131)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:85)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:181)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:227)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:221)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:131)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:151)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.ConcurrentSessionFilter.doFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter.java:129)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at deployment.my-app-web.war//org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.1.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.lambda$handleRequest$1(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.4.SP01-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.FlexibleIdentityAssociation.runAsFunctionEx(FlexibleIdentityAssociation.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.4.SP01-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAsFunctionEx(Scoped.java:161)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.2.4.SP01-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.security.auth.server.Scoped.runAs(Scoped.java:73)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server@4.0.1.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.ElytronRunAsHandler.handleRequest(ElytronRunAsHandler.java:67)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:117)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-web.undertow-server-servlet@4.0.1.Final-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.elytron.web.undertow.server.servlet.CleanUpHandler.handleRequest(CleanUpHandler.java:38)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.3.GA-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.3.GA-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.SendErrorPageHandler.handleRequest(SendErrorPageHandler.java:52)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:276)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:132)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.3.GA-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.3.GA-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.3.GA-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.3.GA-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow@8.0.3.GA-redhat-00001//org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1430)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:256)
    at io.undertow.servlet@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:101)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:393)
    at io.undertow.core@2.3.14.SP1-redhat-00001//io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:859)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final-redhat-00001//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at org.jboss.xnio@3.8.16.Final-redhat-00001//org.xnio.XnioWorker$WorkerThreadFactory$1$1.run(XnioWorker.java:1282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)

What I tried
I checked if I can pass multipart config through standalone.xml via <jsp-config/> but looked into the code, and org.wildfly.extension.undertow.JSPConfig class does not has such fields.
Then tried to override jsp servlet with <jsp-config/> removed from standalone.xml and inside web.xml with such entries
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        <multipart-config>
            <max-file-size>10485760</max-file-size>
            <max-request-size>20971520</max-request-size>
            <file-size-threshold>5242880</file-size-threshold>
        </multipart-config>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jspx</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

But such config does not work, as I should at least call io.undertow.jsp.JspServletBuilder#setupDeployment during server startup to register tag libs, which I would rather not do.
Last (and my biggest disapointment) was this part of servlets configuration:
class io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedServlet#ManagedServlet in constructor calls method setupMultipart. When multipart config is not present on servlet that is being initialized it tries to get it from some defaults
if(multipartConfig == null) {
  multipartConfig = servletContext.getDeployment().getDeploymentInfo().getDefaultMultipartConfig();
}

Unfortunately a setter to this field in class io.undertow.servlet.api.DeploymentInfo is not called when object is being initialized in org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService
What I expect
To pass multipart configuration to auto generated jsp servlet.
